# How to create custom string column of concatenated values in Excel(PivotTable Report)

Tags: excel, excel-2016

How do you create a custom string column in Excel 2016(using PivotTable Report) with a concatenated string of one of the base table's columns?

I'm trying to roll up all the products within an associated brand(i.e. a brand has multiple products).

Sample data:

```
Brand   Product      MPG
-----   -------      ------
Toyota  RAV4         20 
Toyota  Camry        25
Toyota  4Runner      18
Nissan  Pathfinder   18
Nissan  Versa        25
```

I want the output of the summarized data to be like this:

```
Brand     Products               Brand Avg MPG  
-------   --------               --------
Toyota    RAV4, Camry, 4Runner   21.00
Nissan    Pathfinder, Versa      21.50
```

Thanks!

[image: Excel 2016 version info]

Comment: Is the data you are showing in a Pivot Table?  Or is it raw data?  Is using a Pivot table required?  I ask because VBA code, at least conceptually, might be simpler without dealing with a Pivot Table.  Why not try that?

Comment: When I pull the data in from the external source, I choose the "PivotTable Report" option in Excel, which is the best option for other things like filtering and summarizing metrics. Those are not the only columns(or rows) that come in from the external source, just a sample.

Comment: Ok.  I suggest you write VBA code and treat the area where the Pivot Table is located as a Range.  You'll need to work in some routines to locate the Table, and also to update the range if/when the Pivot table gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PivotTable Grouping feature to do this.

[image]

This will make your PivotTable look like a mess initially:

[image]

Drag the Product field out of the PivotTable Fields List, leaving the new Product2 field:

[image]

Then click on the *Group1* label and overtype it with what you want:

[image]

Then repeat for the other field:

[image]

[image]

It will be possible to write some VBA that does this automatically, if there are too many to do manually.

It also may be possible to use PowerQuery/PowerPivot to do this, but I'd need to know exactly what version AND SKU of Excel is involved i.e. not just the year number but also the highlighted bit in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Did the udf method(SlicerItems) not work? I had not tried it yet.

Comment: I realized that it wasn't going to fix your issue, whereas the above does.

Comment: In the default case(i.e. no filters applied to the base table), or even for a handful, doing this manually would be too tedious or time-consuming. I'll see if I can do this with VBA.

Comment: Cool...I might have a crack at this myself as it would lend itself to content for a book I'm working on. But no promises...

Comment: Question: Do you still want them to be able to say filter out a particular product (say Camry) and have that label automatically update? If so, this solution won't work for you, and you'll have to go down the UDF route after all (which thinking again, probably would work).

Comment: Yes, the user could filter out any brand, product or mpg values.

Comment: OK. What version/SKU of Excel do they have? e.g. Excel Office365 Professional Plus.

Comment: 2016, thick-client(not browser) version, 365 ProPlus.

Comment: SKU? e.g. "Professional Plus"? See the screenshot I added to the end of my answer